# Grouping of measurements by interval between them

Tags: c#, graph, statistics, grouping

For a project I'm taking measurements of air pressure at a very high interval (1-5ms). If the pressure has changed within a margin of error I add that data to my list. An example would look like this:

```
timestamp (ms)   pressure (%)
311                 10
714                 16
844                  4
941                 31
977                 55
1080                65
1211                27
```

This data is taken and displayed live, which works perfectly with OxyPlot for WPF.
Data is kept in memory - so no need to access a database, file or something else.

In addition to the live data I want to display it in a very specific grouping but I don't know what it is called (clustering I think) nor how to do it.

But let me explain - I want to organize the data to later plot a graph where:

- X = time difference to previous entry (in Hz but that is a simple 1000/x)
- Y = pressure %

Edit to clarify: For each time difference (X) there should be a column for each pressure value that occured after the given interval.

This is what the result should look like:
[image: This is what it should look like]

This graph should only consist of the last x entries of my complete list (e.g. 1000) and be updated every second or so. I know how to do this the brute force way by looping trough everything and creating nested Arrays. But that certainly can't be the optimal way to do it. So how do I group my dataset to achieve this?

Any help highly appreciated!

Comment: I think it would be better to show us your **input** of program, and the **output** that you expect, make it more easily to being understood.

Comment: Ok, thought is was clear from the table and screenshot. Input is a List<Point> with X being the timestamp (in ms) and Y being pressure as percentage. Output should be a map of time intervals (in Hertz) with the value being a list of all pressure readings within that interval.

Answer (score 0):

Already found what I needed! If anyone is looking for something similar, here is what I found out:

The thing I was looking for is basically a transformation of time data into its frequency bands. It's a very complex mathematical topic I don't really understand - and luckily don't have to, because there are a lot of libraries that do exactly that.

Such a transformation is called an Fourier Transformation. With the terms FFT (Fast ..) or DFT (Discrete ..) there are a lot of resources to choose from.

Hope that helps someone one day! :)